# Plot of prediction by ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, data-visualization, prediction

After fitting an `ARIMA` model to data, how can we `plot` the predicted value plus the original observation in one figure?
`plot` works well with `auto.arima`, but I could not find the relevant function in `arima` model!

***Right ANSWER:***

```
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(USAccDeaths, order=c(0,1,1), seasonal=c(0,1,1))
fit %>% forecast() %>% autoplot()
```

With special thanks to **Prof. Hyndman**. (@Rob-Hyndman)

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(USAccDeaths, order=c(0,1,1), seasonal=c(0,1,1))
fit %>% forecast() %>% autoplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Dear Professor Hyndman, the codes worked well and your solved the problem. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, where you would of course probably also want to plot the original time series etc.

```
y <- arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=0.9), n=120)
y.is <- y[1:100] # in-sample und ...
y.oos <- y[101:120] # out-of-sample 
reg.AR1 <- arima(y.is, order=c(1,0,0))
fore.AR1 <- predict(reg.AR1, n.ahead=20)$pred
plot(fore.AR1)
```